# How to make bottom of the cube narrower if there are edges in the middle of it?

Tags: transforms, edges

So, I'm quite new to blender, I am not very familiar with all the terms, so, please bear with me. But I've encountered a rather confusing problem here, since I do not know how to search for the solution in this case.

First I start with inserting a cube. And then I switch to edit mode, select the bottom 4 vertices, press S, and y to scale in the y-axis. And drag towards the middle:
[image: image 1]

This works perfectly as I want.

But if I extrude at the top, and then I do the same,

1. By selecting all the 4 bottom vertices:
   [image: image 2]
2. By selecting all the bottom vertices and the middle ones:
   [image: image 3]

How can I achieve the same effect as I did without extruding anything?

One way I thought is by bringing together first, and then split the figure using Ctrl+R. But I have some figures that I've already done all the extrusion and editing with them, and it would be a pain to recreate them.

Edit:
The so-called "accurate" method seems to also cause some issues.
[image: image 4]
There is a slight bend where I have pointed above, which is exactly what I want to avoid. This was performed after selecting the bottom 8 vertices into the group.

Comment: I thought increasing the accuracy would help, but blender crashes.

Answer (score 1):

### Fast but limited method

You can do it approximately using proportional editing:

[image]

Use <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> scroll to change the radius of effect while in transform:

[image: demo GIF]

You can try different falloff types like *Linear* or *Sphere*, but eventually they all will squish the center of action more than the far side of the radius.

### Slow but accurate method

Create a deform cube around the area you want to deform, then add a Mesh Deform modifier on the original cube and set the deform cube as target:

[image]

Then select the original cube, <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into edit mode, select the vertices you don't want to stay in place, and hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> to assign them to a new group.

Put that group in the modifier, hit the <kbd>bind</kbd> button, then switch to the deform cube in edit mode, and scale down the bottom vertices:

[image: demo GIF 2]

Once you are happy with the result, hover the modifier and hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to apply it.

Comment: Nice ideas. I already tried the inaccurate method with my other figures, but it had caused many other vertices to misalign and cause problems. I like the accurate way. Nice.

Comment: What do you think about my question? How do you think I can improve the next ones I may ask? What details are important to be included in these blender questions?

Comment: @Exampleperson For the inaccurate method I would try setting the _Falloff_ to _Linear_ instead of the default _Smooth_ as shown here, that's at least a bit less inaccurate. And of course limit it to the Y axis (or restrict it from the Z axis) so that the middle edge doesn't come down while scaling.

Comment: Still, there seems to be some degree of misalignment there in the accurate way. Why is that, and any way to overcome that? Especially when the edges that cut the cube are not really in the same place in the front and the back, if you understand what I mean.

Comment: For example, it seems to be a bit oriented to the 2nd example in my question. Increasing the accuracy just crashes my blender. My blender is the latest release.

Comment: Selecting all the vertices of the original cube into the group helps, and seems to be more accurate. But the top vertices also move.

Comment: Also, I found that making the mesh cube as the same size as the original cube gives the best results. But still there is some kind of tiny issues in the bottom of the cube, etc.